# interpretting describe outputs in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I don't understand why the mean values are different between `describe()` and `mean()` output.

[image]

Comment: Interesting. Can you do `rateDF.IndividualTobaccoRate.isnull().sum()` please?

Comment: `rateDF.IndividualTobaccoRate.isnull().sum() = 7007146`

Comment: It's very possible that one of the two methods do not consider nulls.

Comment: May be, but then it is even not the same number for the column which doesn't have null. `rateDF.IndividualRate.isnull().sum() = 0`

Comment: I just experimented with some sample data and they do indeed treat NaNs the same. So, would you mind restarting your kernel and running these same commands? Make sure you do not change/modify the data in any manner.

Comment: Interesting, the kernel reboot fixed the issue. Wacky ...

Comment: I'm pretty sure your data had been inadvertently modified somehow. Anyway, good to know it's fixed. Would've had to log a bug on the pandas repo otherwise.